# How to apply google voice in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-text-to-speech

I try to call google voice.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    const string apiString = "http://translate.google.com/translate_ttsie=UTF-8&q={0}&tl{1}";      

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "en";
        WindowsMediaPlayer p = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
        p.settings.volume = 100;
        p.URL=string.Format(apiString,System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text),Label1.Text);
    }
```

It does not read the text. What to do?

Comment: You can't use WindowsMediaPlayer in an ASP.NET scenario. Windows Media Player runs on the machine where the server is, not on the client machine.

Comment: Than how to make google voice to read my text on my web?

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. Google Voice is a VoIP phone service. It doesn't do text to speech. Anyways, if you want text to speech on your site, you'll need to find a suitable client side library, or perform the text to speech on the server, save the results, and send them to the client. All of which is far too broad to explain. You'll need to do you own research.

Comment: Thanks for help!